# making soundpool for tempo

Tags: android, soundpool

I am developing a drum machine with 12 buttons that can play different sounds.I want to add soundpool that plays every " " second and i want to be able to adjust time between soundpool starts in application.I know how to set up soundpool,but i want to learn how to set up delay between soundpool starts again.
Any help will be appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this link will help you for how to start one sound and stop and start another and stop if this link will not help than tell me I will send another answer.

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/getting-your-feet-wet-in-androids-soundpool/877/

Comment: the link is broken, any idea where you can get this?